# Spinner when apex is loading LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, spinner, lazy-loading

Hi I am new in programming and salesforce.
I want to add spinner like "https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/lightning-spinner-in-lwc-lightning-web-component/" or just gif when my apex class is loading before click button. Can u help me ?

**Apex class**

```
public with sharing class StockMarketSharesWrapper {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<Wrapper> getAllCompanys(){
   
       

        // Define the list
        List<Wrapper> com = new List<Wrapper>(); 


        // Create account sObjects
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'U';
        w.Name = 'Unity Software Inc';
        Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();
        w1.Ticker = 'UAL';
        w1.Name = 'United Airlines Holdings, Inc.' ;
        Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();
        w2.Ticker ='DAOOU' ;
        w2.Name = 'Crypto 1 Acquisition Corp Unit';
        Wrapper w3 = new Wrapper();
        w3.Ticker = 'GLLIU';
        w3.Name ='Globalink Investment Inc. Unit' ;

        // Add accounts to the list
        com.add(w);
        com.add(w1);
        com.add(w2);
        com.add(w3);

        return com;
    }

    public class Wrapper{

@AuraEnabled
public String Name {get; set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Ticker {get; set;}

} 

}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>

    <lightning-card variant="Narrow">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item
                size="12"
                padding="around-small"
            >
            <div class="slds-grid">
            <!--Search place for text-->
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-input type="text"
                    value=''
                    ></lightning-input>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-var-m-top_large slds-var-p-right_medium">
                    <!--Search Button-->
                    <div class="slds-col">
                        <lightning-button 
                        label="Search"
                        onclick={showSearchResults}
                        variant="brand"></lightning-button>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    
            
                    <lightning-datatable if:true={showCompanies} data={companys.data} columns={columns} key-field="Name"></lightning-datatable>
  
                                   
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<lightning-spinner if:false={companys.data}>
</lightning-spinner>
```

This will show the standard Salesforce spinner until the data has loaded.

Eventually, you may have to handle error conditions, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: `lightning-datatable` also has `is-loading` prop that the OP can use if the component only has datatable that depends on the spinner.

Comment: @SachinHooda True. I'd forgotten about that, but in this specific case, they are hiding the table until a button is pressed.